# How to determine if a query can potentially deadlock in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, locking, deadlock

When implementing database queries I'm often wondering if the query I'm writing can potentially deadlock when executed in parallel by many clients. Often I only find out by running the query in parallel with a large number of clients to see if I'm getting the infamous ["deadlock detected"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/286040/215082) in practice.

I'm wondering if there is a more formal approach to determine if a query has the potential to deadlock? By "more formal" I mean something like:

- Is it possible to inspect/explain what the query is doing under the hood even when executed in isolation and judge from e.g. some internal logs that a deadlock is possible? If I could for instance see the exact locks that are needed and their order, I could probably predict if it can deadlock. In practice, I often just don't know if the query is locking on table or on row level. In such a case the assumption would be e.g. that a single table lock is fine, but locking multiple rows non-atomically brings the deadlock potential, because another instance of the query could lock the rows in a different order.
- If it isn't possible via inspecting logs, are there some general patterns to look for in queries that are a potential deadlock?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a principled formal approach to this. Besides, while it can happen, it is not a frequent occurrence that a single statement deadlocks with the same statement run in a second session. Usually, the other statements that ran in the same transaction and also take locks are just as important.

The simple tricks to reduce the likelihood of a deadlock are:

- keep the transactions as short as possible
- don't bundle any more data modifications in a single transaction than are necessary to guarantee the consistency of your data

When that is done, you can strive for more by making sure that resources are always locked in a certain order. That order is often hard to determine and will depend on the execution plan chose by the statement (which you can find with `EXPLAIN`). To give you an example:

```
UPDATE tab
SET col = 42
WHERE val = 'changeme';
```

There is no guarantee that the rows will be locked in a certain order. You could instead try the following which is somewhat more expensive, but will do better in this respect:

```
WITH myrows AS (
   SELECT id
   FROM tab
   WHERE val = 'changeme'
   ORDER BY id
   FOR NO KEY UPDATE
)
UPDATE tab
SET col = 42
FROM myrows
WHERE tab.id = myrows.id;
```

I'm not saying that there is a guarantee that the latter statement will never deadlock with anything, but it has better odds not to deadlock with itself than the former statement.